# Differentiate trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The question is to Differentiate the following with respect to x

\begin{align}
Q1.   \sin^3x 
    \end{align}

The answer given is
\begin{align}
      3\sin^2x \cos x
    \end{align}

I am not sure how they got this answer so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Chain Rule, where the derivative of $f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Let $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$, so that $f(g(x))=(\sin(x))^3$.

Apply the chain rule to get $3\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: So do I first apply the chain rule than use the product rule?

Comment: The product rule doesn't need to be used. You are not multiplying two functions together, but you are taking sin(x) and putting it into x^3 to get sin(x)^3

Comment: The derivative of x^3 is 3x^2, so you have 3sin(x)^2

Comment: Then, derivative of sin(x) is cos(x), so that is g'(x) that you tack onto the end

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Rewrite $\sin^3x$ as $(\sin x)^3$ and apply the chain rule.